# javascript parseInt - difference of calculation in different radix

Tags: javascript

For base19 and base24 both, value of a is 10 and b is 11 that I know.

But 
`parseInt("ab", 19) returns 201` and `parseInt("ab", 24) returns 251`.

I want to know that how calculation is being done in each case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's easy

```
10(a)*19 = 190 + 11(b) = 201

10(a)*24 = 240 + 11(b) = 251
```

[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) is the wikipedia article on how to use positional notation and [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/base-conversion-method.html) a simple tutorial on base conversion.